# transparent redirect example.com/ex -> ip address

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, bind, cpanel

How to do a redirect like this:
example.com/example -> XXX.XXX.XX.XX an ip address ?

Using .htaccess or bind via cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect 301 example.com/example XXX.XXX.XX.XX
```